# Attempting to Model Air Resistance in Javelin Flight

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, projectile, drag, aerodynamics

I am trying to do a mathematical modelling project on javelin flight and correlate the data to real life data from the Olympics. Obviously, drag is an important component of the flight characteristics. I have been searching lots of places trying to find an intuitive explanation of the equations explaining both lift and drag but I am unable to find any that work. The equations cannot be too complicated as I am still in high school (if too complicated the teacher will presume we plagiarised others work). Can anyone help me with this problem and explain the equations of lift and drag in projectile motion?